# Importing JSON into Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have to following JSON that is coming from an API (e.g. my_json). The array of entities is stored in a key called entities:

```
{
    "action" : "get",
    "application" : "4d97323f-ac0f-11e6-b1d4-0eec2415f3df",
    "params" : {
      "limit" : [ "2" ]
    },
    "path" : "/businesses",
    "entities" : [
        {
            "uuid" : "508d56f1-636b-11e7-9928-122e0737977d",
            "type" : "business",
            "size" : 730 },
        {
            "uuid" : "2f3bd4dc-636b-11e7-b937-0ad881f403bf",
            "type" : "business",
            "size" : 730 
        } ],
  "timestamp" : 1499469891059,
  "duration" : 244,
  "count" : 2
}
```

I am trying to load them into a data frame as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_json(my_json['entities'], orient='split')
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <type 'list'>
```

I have tried records orientation and still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please add `my_json`'s content to your question?

Answer (score 30):

If `my_json` is a dictionary as I suspect, then you can skip the `pd.read_json` and just do

```
pd.DataFrame(my_json['entities'])

   size      type                                  uuid
0   730  business  508d56f1-636b-11e7-9928-122e0737977d
1   730  business  2f3bd4dc-636b-11e7-b937-0ad881f403bf
```

Comment: This totally worked for me ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

The way you are using `my_json['entities']` makes it look like it is a Python `dict`.

According to the [`pandas` documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html), `read_json` takes in "a valid JSON string or file-like". You can convert a `dict` into a json string with the following:

```
import json
json_str = json.dumps(my_json["entities"])
```

The data under the key `"entities"` as you have described it does not fit the formatting strategy for `orient="split"`. It looks like you will need to use `orient="list"`:

```
import pandas as pd

my_json = """{
    "entities": [
            {
                "type": "business",
                "uuid": "199bca3e-baf6-11e6-861b-0ad881f403bf",
                "size": 918
            },
            {
                "type": "business",
                "uuid": "054a7650-b36a-11e6-a734-122e0737977d",
                "size": 984
            }
        ]
}"""

print pd.read_json(my_json, orient='list')
```

yielding:

```
                                              entity
0  {u'type': u'business', u'uuid': u'199bca3e-baf...
1  {u'type': u'business', u'uuid': u'054a7650-b36...
```

or

```
import pandas as pd

my_json = """[
    {
        "type": "business",
        "uuid": "199bca3e-baf6-11e6-861b-0ad881f403bf",
        "size": 918
    },
    {
        "type": "business",
        "uuid": "054a7650-b36a-11e6-a734-122e0737977d",
        "size": 984
    }
]"""

print pd.read_json(my_json, orient='list')
```

yielding:

```
   size      type                                  uuid
0   918  business  199bca3e-baf6-11e6-861b-0ad881f403bf
1   984  business  054a7650-b36a-11e6-a734-122e0737977d
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the official [documenation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) orient is suppose to be 'records'

```
df = pd.read_json(json.dumps(b_j['entities']) , orient='records')
```

Answer (score 1):

danielcorin pointed me in the right direction. I ended up having to do:

```
pd.read_json(json.dumps(b_j['entities']) , orient='list')
```

The read_json method takes a string so I dump the entities collection and use that.

Answer (score 0):

It raises the error because type of your variable is `list`, as stated at the end of the error.

Actually this makes it easier to stack into dataframe, because you can stack lists into a dataframe directly.
Hence you can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(my_json['entities'])
```