# "ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'dict'>" from pd.read_json

Tags: python, json, pandas

```
url = 'https://apps.grupoice.com/CenceWeb/data/sen/json/DemandaMW?inicio=20190101&fin20190131'
datos = requests.get(url)
print(datos.status_code)
datos_json = datos.json()
datos_df = pd.read_json(datos_json)
```

I get the following error:

> ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'dict'>

I need to get the link data in json format and then convert it to dataframe, but it gives me this error.

Comment: For which line do you get this error?

Comment: @mkrieger1 the last line

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing JSON into Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44980845/importing-json-into-pandas)

Answer (score 1):

The object returned by `datos.json()` is a `dict` and not a string or buffer or path as expected by `pd.read_json`.

Instead, use `pd.Dataframe.from_dict`

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = 'https://apps.grupoice.com/CenceWeb/data/sen/json/DemandaMW?inicio=20190101&fin20190131'
datos = requests.get(url)
print(datos.status_code)
datos_json = datos.json()
datos_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(datos_json)
```